# isc-dhcp send packet not permitted when using iptables snat

Tags: linux, iptables, isc-dhcp

I'm having this issue with iptables snat and isc dhcp. This is the case:

I have configured 2 IPs in my network card. Primary and secondary

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

```
2: ens32: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:40:7a:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet **10.232.208.228**/29 brd 10.232.208.231 scope global ens32
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet **10.232.208.229**/29 brd 10.232.208.231 scope global secondary ens32
```

When a DHCP request comes to secondary IP(10.232.208.229), ISC DHCP create a DHCP Offer with the primary IP(10.232.208.228) as source. I used the following iptable snat rule to solve the issue:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -o ens32 -s 10.232.208.228 --sport 67:68 -j SNAT --to-source 10.232.208.229:67
```

The problem is that when i translate to 10.232.208.229:67, the DHCPOffer packet is not sent. If i change the port for any other than 67, it works.

Here is the log on syslog telling that Operation not permitted:

```
Jul 28 11:46:31 dhcp777rsv2 dhcpd[32364]: DHCPDISCOVER from d0:67:e5:30:18:90 (MXXXX) via 172.16.199.1
Jul 28 11:46:32 dhcp777rsv2 dhcpd[32364]: DHCPOFFER on 172.16.199.4 to d0:67:e5:30:18:90 (MXXXX) via 172.16.199.1
Jul 28 11:46:32 dhcp777rsv2 dhcpd[32364]: **send_packet: Operation not permitted**
Jul 28 11:46:32 dhcp777rsv2 dhcpd[32364]: dhcp.c:3693: **Failed to send 301 byte long packet over fallback interface.**
```

my iptable table do not have other rules, and by default it permits everthing.

I have tried running dhcpd with root user without luck.

I would like to understand what is happening and could solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Reading in netfilter.org i found what was my problem and solved it.

I had to add a PREROUTING DNAT rule to make this work:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d 10.232.208.229 --dport 67:68 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.232.208.228
```

The reason is that the incoming packet created a connection using source x.x.x.x:67 dest:10.232.208.229:67 and because this connection already exist, the system can not NAT a packet matching an existing connection.